# What is the minimum HTML/Javascript required for an app?

Tags: cordova

I am trying to make a very simple Apache Cordova app. I know it offers features which are not normally available on websites but are available on phones. But I don't need them. I need to make a very simple website, just HTML and CSS. 
So what is the minimum HTML/CSS/Javascript code for an Apache Cordova app? Can I remove all files in `MyProject\platforms\browser\www` and just put there mine?

Comment: Sure, if you want. Why make an app in that case, though, if a simple mobile website would suffice?

Comment: So it can be installed and have a nice icon somewhere on the phone

Comment: You can use "Add to Home Screen" for that. Read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html, particularly the bits about specifying the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute minimum is one HTML-file within the www folder.

This file will be displayed. You won't need any javascript or CSS.

But, in this case you wouldn't need cordova at all. Just [add your website to the homescreen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen). It is easier to update and you won't need an appstore approval.

Apple, may scan your APP and encounter, that it is a simple website-wrapper. As far as I know, this kind of Apps wouldn't be approved. In this case you may need to use some APIs. This would mean, that you will have to register for the [Device-Ready Event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready).

Answer (score 2):

Once you install latest Cordova CLI, just execute the following command in command prompt:

`cordova create PROJECT_NAME`

This command creates a basic Cordova project with bare minimum HTML and JavaScripts required. All you gotta do is edit them according to your need, add platform, build it and run it.